# .Net Blazor Server Excel Viewer

Tags: .net, blazor

I am looking for a way to display an Excel spreadsheet including cell formatting in a Blazor Server app.  Kind of a simple Excel Viewer.

I want to display from the image below only what is in the red frame. Incl. the cell colours and so on.
The display needs no menus, no scrolling, no context menu, no editing  etc. It just needs to be displayed exactly the same as in the original Excel.

In my application, I need to select the correct sheet (year) depending of the actual date  and automatically horizontal shift to the current week.
The user can’t scroll. The correct region has to be displayed based on the actual date fully automatically.

Which component is the best to solve this?

[image]

Comment: i think you have to use a 3rd party nuget package for this.

Comment: Ok, thanks, any suggestion for a good nuget for this task?

Comment: A cross-platform .NET library for reading and writing Excel data files.https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan.Data.Excel. It's open source with MIT license.

Comment: And also it's a BlazorExcelViewer rep, However, It's not visualized as you'd like.https://github.com/ieei0214/BlazorExcelViewer

Comment: It's a yotube about this.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBixyTeEK4E, And, this one is third party lib with syncfusion, However, it's not free.https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/create-read-edit-excel-files-in-blazor-c-sharp

Comment: @Arani Thanks a lot to all your input. i will take a good look at all this, thank you very much